# I want to design one graph in "d3.js". what could be the best representation of this data in the form of bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Which graph is suitable for this data and how we can draw that graph?

I have one csv which contain 6 columns and I want to develop one bar chart with the help of that data. My data is as follows:

```
    Region  Year   Quarter   Month      Category   Volume
    AMER    2015    4         12         R          10
    APAC    2015    4         12         H           2
    EMEA    2015    4         12         N           5
    ATAM    2015    4         12         R          15
    AMER    2016    4         1          H          43
    APAC    2016    4         1          N          23
    EMEA    2016    4         1          R          65
    ATAM    2016    4         1          H          22
    AMER    2016    1         2          N          54
    APAC    2016    1         2          R          8
    EMEA    2016    1         2          H          2
    ATAM    2016    1         2          N          3
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at https://bl.ocks.org/ to see if any of the examples fit your expectations. I guess a bar chart with tooltips to display more data (http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) would work, but without knowing what your data shows, or what you want to demonstrate, no one can tell you what would be suitable.

Comment: I made 3 graphs and now I have to make dashboard out of it. How can I make that using d3js???

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. What do you want the dashboard to do? Are you trying to combine the graphs? Or switch between them?